# Удаление повторяющихся значений ms sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, select

Есть таблица в БД.Ежедневно в полночь устройства присылают данные. Одно устройство может прислать несколько значений.(Пример в изображении)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо составить запрос к таблице, в котором произойдет выборка данных за все время, но выберутся только строки в которых:
1) Даты в текущем диапазоне
2) Даты для одного устройства не повторяются
3) У выбранной даты будет максимальное значение

Сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT DeviceID, Time, Value 
FROM [ADDAXDB_APPSERVER].[dbo].[RW_ReceivedData] t1
WHERE Unit=30 
  AND Value>1000 
  AND DATEPART(hour, Time) = '00' 
  AND YEAR(Time)='2019'
ORDER BY DeviceId, [Time]
```

Еще буду благодарен, если увидев неоптимальные решения поможете их решить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, так:

```
SELECT DeviceID, CAST([Time] AS DATE), MAX(Value) AS Value
FROM [ADDAXDB_APPSERVER].[dbo].[RW_ReceivedData] t1
WHERE Unit=30 
  AND Value>1000 
  AND YEAR(Time)='2019'
GROUP BY DeviceId, CAST([Time] AS DATE)
```

Если поле `[Time]` имеет тип DATE, то CAST() не требуется.